# What exactly is this terminal command doing?

Tags: linux, terminal, copy

`cp EFI/boot/loader.efi to EFI/boot/bootx64.efi`

I understand that this is the copy command, but what exactly happens to files individually when this command is run on them. Do we get duplicate files or do we get only one file? I am trying to recreate the action on Windows, as I do not have `sudo` access on the linux I am working on.

I got this command from a question on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/615142/uefi-failed-to-install-override-security-policy) forum. Please do not ask any more questions as to clarify this question. Thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This copies looder.efi to bootx64.efi. If the bootx64.efi file does not already exist, the cp command creates it. If it does exist, the cp command replaces its contents with the contents of the looder.efi file.